# Kibana Alerting - Monitors Disappearing and Alerts are not triggering automatically

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, alert, monitoring, elasticsearch-opendistro

the issue is in our kibana monitors are getting lost by themselves and after 2-3 mins they come back
[[image: monitors disappeared1]

Normally alerts were being created as expected

[image: normally alerts were working as expected]

Second and the most important one is alerts are not triggering even if the condition result is true.
[image: triggered alert!]

Condition Response true!!

[image: condition response]

So anyone faced this issue, i'm open to advices. Thanks a lot since now.

Comment: I've moved my logs to another Kibana version by Remote Cluster option and issue done √